# Home LAN without Internet connection

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, switch

Is it possible to configure a home network without internet connection (just for file sharing) using  the following scheme:

```
| PC w/ UbuntuServer 12.04 | -- |                 |

| PC w/ Ubuntu and Windows | -- | [D-Link switch] |

| Something else  ...      | -- |                 |
```

And, if answer is yes, how can I do this without buying anything else?

Comment: What is the model of the "D-Link switch"? Are you sure it's just a switch?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes..

Answer (score 3):

Install and configure a [DHCP server](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-and-configure-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu-server.html) on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: yep.  If the d-link is a router (not a plain switch), then it can be the DHCP server.

Comment: also, you dont *need* a DHCP server, you can configure the IPs manually.

Comment: @Keltari uh.. what if d-link is exactly a plain switch?

Comment: @treng: Then you either need a DHCP server or you need to configure all IP addresses manually.

Comment: DHCP is a comfy possibility but not needed for the above setup. The straight answer is: 1) You only NEED the switch for the above to work. 2) There is absolutely no need for router functionality. 3) DHCP makes your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a router is needed for this, although you can set it up with just a switch but you won’t be able to use the DHCP features without IPv4 addresses, which switches don’t work at. But as the guys suggested below, if it’s a router then enable it as a DHCP server and connect using IPs to other machines etc.